# Kendo UI Upload button

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I would like to change the text of the Kendo UI Upload button "Select files.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `selectMessageUI` attribiute to change the value of the select button here is an example what rewrite that button value :

```
<Upload 
  selectMessageUI={() => "what ever you want"}
  batch={false} multiple={true} defaultFiles={[]} 
  withCredentials={false} 
  saveUrl={'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service-v4/upload/save'}
  removeUrl={'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service-v4/upload/remove'} 
/>
```

and the result is like this:

[image: image of the result]